# Matlab 2 Python Code Conversion

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a MATLAB .m source code file to Python script. The first few lines of .m file is:

```
clear all
close all
clc
```

Below is my code for Python counterpart code for:

**clear all:**

```
def clearall():
    """clear all globals"""
    for uniquevar in [var for var in globals().copy() if var[0] != "_" and var != 'clearall']:
        del globals()[uniquevar]
```

**clc:**

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

clear
```

But I am not getting what should be code counterpart for MATLAB '*close all*' ? Also are my above code references correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest that you consider if you convert any of those three functions at all.

If you write a script in Python and start it over and over again in most of the cases for such a scenario a dedicated interpreter should and will be started. Such a fresh interpreter is out of the box unaffected by previous variable definitions and will also get a clean screen to write to (empty command window). However if you are using an IDE there are sometimes side effects which behave like a restart of the script without cleaning all previously defined variables but in that case you will have other problems, too.

To answer your question what counterpart "close all" would have in Python I would say it would be dependent of the plotting library you are using. For Matlab, the line will close every opened figure which was started in your script. In Python a figure will only live as long as the interpreter runs and it will be closed along as the interpreter shuts down. If you want to close figures intermediary you have to close them explicitly.